# Provisioning Profile not found for app store distribution

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile, provisioning

I am trying to submit my app to the app store through Xamarin Studio. But I am getting an error saying No valid provisioning profiles found. I have a development certificate and an app store provisioning profile set up. Not sure why it's not finding it.

Comment: A couple of ideas off the top of my head: Could be because of missing entitlements? Or that the provisioning profile you have does not include the signing identity you are using?

Comment: Does the app name match the app name on the cert?

Comment: @jgoldberger Do i need to add my dev cert to the app store provisioning profile? That's the only thing i can think of but i've been told that's not necessary. Or do I need to create my own distribution cert and add it to the provisioning profile?

And yeah the app name matches the app name on the cert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a distribution certificate.  You cannot submit to the app store with a development certificate. You cannot associate a development certificate with a app store distribution profile.

Ensure you have a iOS Distribution certificate created, and that it is valid when you download it to your Mac (by opening the Keychain Access app, and clicking on the cert - you should see a green check and the word "Valid" by it).

Then create a App Store Distribution provisioning profile and tie it to the certificate.